# Django authenticate is None

Tags: django, django-authentication

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_name = request.POST.get("username",'')
        pass_word = request.POST.get("password",'')
        user = authenticate(user_name=user_name,password=pass_word)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return render(request,'index.html')
        else:
            return render(request,'login.html',{ })
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render(request,"login.html",{ })
```

I've already set up the super user and updated the database, but the backstage password user still returns None

Comment: have you overridden `authenticate`? it doesn't have a `user_name` argument.

Comment: How did you create the super user?

Comment: *python manage.py createsuperuser*

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I haven't noticed that I have a problem here

Comment: if this answer helped you.. you can always accept the answer and upvote  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authenticate` function takes arguments in form:
`authenticate(username='john', password='secret')`.

change

user_name -> username

in arguments

Answer (score 0):

*the default authenticate looks like this*

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
if user is not None:
    # A backend authenticated the credentials
else:
    # No backend authenticated the credentials
```

so i think you need to change ***username*** if you're not ***overriding*** it

Answer (score 0):

```
user = authenticate(username=user_name,password=pass_word)
```

In this line the authenticate function has `username=user_name` not `user_name=user_name` as argument. I think this might be the issue.

Hope this helps :-)